Why is my Asus OLED Slate 13 T3300 stuck at the Asus logo and a motherboard replacement is now recommended by Asus service?
I have an Asus OLED Slate 13 T3300 and I tried to install Linux on it. As the device has eMMC  storage. I needed to write down some commands To be able install Linux:
sudo modprobe -r sdhci_pci sdhci
sudo modprobe sdhci debug_quirks=0x20000
sudo modprobe sdhci_pci

Suddenly the device stopped and when I rebooted, the system was frozen on the ASUS logo. I tried all ways to solve that problem with no luck.
I took it to Asus center in my country at the first diagnosis. They installed the recovery image. Today told me that the motherboard needs to be replaced? I wonder because the device is just stuck on Asus logo

"I wonder because the device is just stuck on asus logo" - Yes; Firmware corruption would explain the system being unable to boot and being stuck on the ASUS logo.

I am adding this link so a relevant question can be linked to this question.

How to make firmware for motherboard

You don't. Loading custom firmware to an OEM motherboard is not a realistic goal

What can i do so ? Please

If still in warranty let them replace the motherboard.

@ahmedshehehta86 - "Today told me that the motherboard needs to be replaced?" - replace the motherboard.
